# JsonConvert SerializeObject : private variable serialize

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, serialization

i use the JsonConvert SerializeObject for serialize object

in my class have private and public variables , public variables are srialize without any problem but private members are not in serialize result

```
 private BOD.clsQuestionStructureInCache cRiskQuestionStruct;

 public List<BOD.clsALLExcessRates> cLstRetunExcessRates;
```

how can i make this as work ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm

You want to use DataContract and DataMember attributes. Every field you want to serialize mark with DataMember attribute and it should work. Code taken from link:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class File
  {
 // excluded from serialization
 // does not have DataMemberAttribute
 public Guid Id { get; set; }

 [DataMember]
 public string Name { get; set; }

 [DataMember]
 public int Size { get; set; }
 }
```